# How to make a validation rule useing another Table

Tags: validation, ms-access-2010

Here is my issue.
I have a table "MainTable" that tracks equipment by the Field "Serial#s"

I have a 2nd table "DOAtable" that has a list of all the Serial#s that we considered to be "DOASerial#s".

When an employee gets an equipment they have to go to table "MainTable" Field "Serial#incoming."

How can I set a validation rule says If the Table "MainTable" Field "Serial#Incoming" entered is in our "DOAtable" Field "DOASerial#s" to give an error message. "Unable to enter this SN# please give equipment to QA Dept."

I'm fairly new to Access and SQL overall so sorry if i'm not able to get my question across correctly.

Comment: Why do you have the MySQL tag if you're using MS-Access?

Comment: You can do it on the data entry form - you can't do it on the Table itself. Use VBA to run your check query on the `BeforeUpdate event` of the `Serial#Incoming text field`.If it finds any records `(.EOF = False)` then set `Cancel = True`